# How do I show 'since <version>' in my Doxygen methods list?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I would like to show something like this on the cppreference website where they put

[image: version number]

with the methods in Doxygen being listed.

I've tried \version and \since but they both get added in the detail view of the method. What do I need to do to add that?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please add a small, complete, example to your question so we can do some experiments.

Comment: Offtopic: cppreference is just a wiki page. If you register you could edit that.

Comment: Version 1.9.2. 
OK but I probably can control somehow what is being shown in the method listing section, it is just for the representation what I want to achieve